# After a nuclear attack for how many turns tiles remain radioactive in civilization 6?

Tags: civilization-6

So I attacked my AI enemy's capital with a submarine-launched nuclear ballistic missile. Now all the tiles around the city are radioactive?

I know that I can probably use military engineers to clear the radiation. But otherwise will the radiations cease to exist after a certain number of turns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to a post made in the Steam Community under Sid Meier's Civilization VI Discussions, a user mentions that the radiation will cease to exist after:

> 10 turns for a regular nuclear device, and 20 turns for a thermonuclear device.

This is confirmed in the Civilization 6 wiki under "Nuclear weapons", linked here:
https://civilization.fandom.com/wiki/Nuclear_weapons_(Civ6)